# Plotly Apache Spark MapBox

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, mapbox

Is there a way to plot Apache Spark Dataframes into MapBox?
I've tried Plotly but it only takes Pandas Dataframes for plotting on maps.

UPDATE:
When I convert Spark to Pandas dataframe, I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o58.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 11 tasks (1097.7 MiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MiB)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2023)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1972)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1971)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1971)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:950)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:950)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:950)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2203)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2152)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:752)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2093)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2114)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2133)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2158)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1004)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1003)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectToPython$1(Dataset.scala:3448)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3616)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:763)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3445)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: you could easily convert the spark dataframe to pandas with `toPandas()` method

Comment: I've tried to optimize this toPandas using arrow, but it errors out because the amount of memory exceeds 1,024MB. Do you know which parameter I need to change to increase the memory?

Comment: can you post the updated code and error message for better context?

Comment: @smurphy0000 I updated the post with the error message.

Comment: Do you have the execution plan? Also it is possible to remove the max result size or set it higher, but at the risk of OOM error